# Automatically loading customization file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-customization

I have customized QGIS menu and toolbars thanks to the customization option and I have created a configuration.ini file that I can load on several machines.

Now, is it possible to create a project and automatically load a specific config.ini file for that project?

I didn't found anything in the project properties or in the option menu, but maybe there is another way.

I am using QGIS 2.1 Master with Debian 7.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't a way to do it using a project file but you can use the `-z` option when starting QGIS.

```
qgis -z custom.ini yourproject.qgs
```

I did think we might be able to do this with project macros but projects are loaded after the customization stuff is applied so out of luck there.