# Qgis -> Settings -> Customization : how to import ini file with python?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

With QGIs, from "Settings"->"Customization" i can hide/show the components of the GUI. 
I can export a INI file with my customization.

There is a way to import my INI file with a python command in the console, without open the customization dialog?

Comment: Have a look at the ConfigParser (py2) / configparser (py3) module in the standard library https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html

Answer (score 1):

With the python subprocess module you should be able to call the terminal to set an .ini file for a project on startup with the command options noted below

```
 --customizationfile
```

> Using this command line argument, you can define a GUI customization
>   file, that will be used at startup.

Or this Q/A answer:

[Is it possible to load automatically a customization file in qgis?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79711/is-it-possible-to-load-automatically-a-customization-file-in-qgis)

Comment: Thanks, I know this option, but it is not the solution that I can take.
I need to load the ini file from a plugin that i'm developing, when qgis has already started.

Comment: QGIS needs to close before an .ini file can be applied.  Maybe in your plugin you can tell the user the app will be closing and re-opening with said .ini applied based on using the subprocess method.