# How to transfer QGIS configurations to latest version?

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-2.18, update

I have QGIS 2.18.11 on my machine. There are saved wms, wfs and DB connections. After installing QGIS 3.0 I can see saved wms connections but no DB connection is listed in 3.0. Collegue's problem is oppposite, he can list DB connections but cannot list WMS connections. How can we transfer 2.18 settings to 3.0?

Comment: related https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79711/is-it-possible-to-load-automatically-a-customization-file-in-qgis

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but are you on Windows/Linux...  On Windows I upgraded to QGIS 3, got an option to keep QGIS 2 settings and I still have all my WMS/WFS/WCS connections.

Comment: I'm on windows PC. I reinstalled QGIS to check for an option for keeping  QGIS2 settins. Unfortunately there is no option in my installer. Probably I takes already existing connection on the PC. I can see wms/wfs connections but cannot see DB connections defined in QGIS2.